# Azure ADF DataFlow failed while writing rows

Tags: azure, export-to-csv, dataflow, azure-data-factory

I have dataflow in Azure Data Factory which convert parquet files into csv.
It works when I have 10 files with a size of 10 KB.
But if I have 3 files with a size of 22 KB there is an error 'failed while writing rows'.

Do you know what is possible solution?

Answer (score 0):

Provided information is not sufficient. You can try increasing core size and also look into below blog if it help you.

[Click Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/383903/data-flow-dfexecutorusererror-failed-while-writing.html)

Comment: However, this is not a problem with the file size but with the 'title' column. Probably some of rows include contain forbidden characters.

Answer (score 0):

Parquet file standard does not allow certain special characters. Use select transform or sink transform to remap these columns to different names. You can do it generically using pattern matching to rename all such columns also.

Comment: Databricks can read it and easily convert to csv.